# public path in localhost and on server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing my application on localhost and I transfer it into server side.

I have a problem with `$path`:

```
$request->file('video')->move($path, $video);
```

on localhost I must use:

```
$request->file('video')->move(
            public_path().'/assets/videos/tutorials\/', $video
        );

//the result of path on server side :"/home/yekidehi/demo/public/assets/videos/tutorials/"
```

but on server side I must use:

```
$request->file('video')->move(
            'assets/videos/tutorials/', $video
        );

//the result of path on server side: 'mydomain.com/assets/video/tutorials/'
```

It takes a lot of time for me. because everytime that I want to upload my codes on server, I must change `$path`.

Is there any solutions?

Comment: Why do you escape `tutorials\/` the last slash? Perhaps thats your problem?

Comment: no, It's not my problem. my problem is two define of path on `server side` and `localhost`.

Comment: Mention URL of both local and server project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put if condition to check that environment is localhost or not,

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "localhost") {
$path=public_path().'/assets/videos/tutorials\/';
}
else{
$path='assets/videos/tutorials/';
}
$request->file('video')->move($path, $video);
```

if condition will work for localhost and else part run when it is live server. hope you will understand.

Thank you